# Trying to use multiple images in opencv imread function but not getting

Tags: python, opencv, imread

```py
import pprint as pp

original_img = cv2.imread("/content/drive/My Drive/images/image1.jpg") #here i want to use multiple images atleast 250 images.

original_img = cv2.cvtColor(original_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
results = tfnet2.return_predict(original_img)
print(results)
```

Comment: Chaideo, in case you have additional information you can provide to make your question clearer, please [edit] your question to add them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess all your images are in the folder images. So you can use `os` to gett all their filenames.

```
import os
pth = "/content/drive/My Drive/images" # make sure it is correct
images = os.listdir(pth)
for image in images:
    image_path = os.path.join(pth, image)
    original_img = cv2.imread(image_path)
    original_img = cv2.cvtColor(original_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    results = tfnet2.return_predict(original_img)
    print(results)
```

Comment: actually i want to use multiple images in imread() line. I already provided import os and no need to give path separetly, thanks

Comment: imread() takes one image argument at a time, so you can't use it to read multiple images in one call without iterating one by one through the images name list. If you want a single-line solution, Vardan's solution could be compacted into a single line, but it would go contrary to good coding practices.

Comment: need to create +500 images json files in  one single line and done it for more images i solved the issue not for just single image file, btw thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

anyone can use for loop add empty folder to direct all the json files directly to the same folder using basic addition '+' operator.

for i in range():

original_img = cv2.imread("/folder path(500+ images)/" + any_empty_folder[i])